# plot. zoo "invalid 'ylim' value"

Tags: r, csv, zoo

When I am trying to plot time-series data with zoo package I am faced with: **Error in plot.window(...) : invalid 'ylim' value**. While plot.zoo gives me the error, plot.ts works fine. plot(mydata) also gives same error.

Data has bee loaded from .csv file which looks like this:

```
    Value
03.01.2011  6.2100
04.01.2011  6.4280
05.01.2011  6.7290
06.01.2011  6.6000
07.01.2011  6.7970
...
```

```
mydata <- read.zoo(mydata, sep = "\t", header = TRUE, format = "%d.%m.%Y", fileEncoding = "UTF-16")
```

> head(mydata)

```
            Value
2011-01-03  6.210
2011-01-04  6.428
2011-01-05  6.729
2011-01-06  6.600
2011-01-07  6.797
```

> dput(mydata)

```
structure(c(" 6.210", " 6.428", " 6.729", " 6.600", " 6.797", " ..."), 
.Dim = c(2023L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "Value"), index = 
structure(c(14977, 14978, 14979, 14980, 14981, ...), class = "Date"), class = "zoo")
```

A data(mydata2) from same source and background works perfectly with plot.zoo. On the contrary it gives me a bit different dput() output. **Values are not between "quotation marks (also no extra space before a first digit)" and I wonder if that's the problem.**

> head(mydata2)

```
            Value
2010-12-31 533.99
2011-01-03 541.30
2011-01-04 548.33
2011-01-05 544.73
2011-01-06 556.61
```

> dput(mydata2)

```
structure(c(533.99, 541.3, 548.33, 544.73, 556.61, ...), 
.Dim = c(2023L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "Value"), index = 
structure(c(14974, 14977, 14978, 14979, 14980, ...), class = "Date"), class = "zoo")
```

I have used read.zoo provided above to both .csv files to load the data into R. Both have tab ("\t") as separator, date format is 03.01.2019 ("%d.%m.%Y"), file encoding ("UTF-16"). I fail to understand why one data is loaded with extra space and quotation marks, which I believe is the reason for error in plot.zoo function.

> sapply(readLines(mydata, 6, skipNul = TRUE), charToRaw)

```
$`\tValue`
[1] 09 43 6c 6f 73 65

$`03.01.2011\t6.2100`
 [1] 30 33 2e 30 31 2e 32 30 31 31 09 36 2e 32 31 30 30

$`04.01.2011\t6.4280`
 [1] 30 34 2e 30 31 2e 32 30 31 31 09 36 2e 34 32 38 30

$`05.01.2011\t6.5900`
 [1] 30 35 2e 30 31 2e 32 30 31 31 09 36 2e 35 39 30 30

$`06.01.2011\t6.6000`
 [1] 30 36 2e 30 31 2e 32 30 31 31 09 36 2e 36 30 30 30

$`07.01.2011\t6.7970`
 [1] 30 37 2e 30 31 2e 32 30 31 31 09 36 2e 37 39 37 30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question did not provide the input so we can't know precisely what is happening but presumably there are characters that it does not understand and render either as space or not rendered at all in the input so it regards the input is character data.

`read.zoo` uses `read.table` and if you read it with that you will likely observe the same problem.

You could force the data to be numeric.  This works for me:

```
library(zoo)

z <- structure(c(" 6.210", " 6.428", " 6.729", " 6.600", " 6.797"), 
.Dim = c(5L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "Value"), index = 
structure(c(14977, 14978, 14979, 14980, 14981), class = "Date"), class = "zoo")

zz <- zoo(array(as.numeric(coredata(z)), dim(z)), index(z))
str(zz)
```

giving:

```
‘zoo’ series from 2011-01-03 to 2011-01-07
  Data: num [1:5, 1] 6.21 6.43 6.73 6.6 6.8
  Index:  Date[1:5], format: "2011-01-03" "2011-01-04" "2011-01-05" "2011-01-06" "2011-01-07"
```

Comment: Yes, this solves my problem. I added a view of .csv file to post. I am not sure if you meant that by an input. If possible I would still like to know what causes this weird non-numeric vector for "Values".  As the goal is to automate everything, the less lines of code, the better. Thank you.

Comment: The text shown in not a csv file and does not have any tabs so something likely has been lost in posting it.

Comment: This is untouched version of csv file opened in plain-text editor (http://i.imgur.com/lMwInb6.png). I have only deleted lines to make it shorter. This is a tab, when I want to open it with Excel or R, tab is the only option that will import it correctly. I do not see any other option possible, it certainly is not a single or multiple spaces.

Comment: Try reading the first few lines and examine the hex codes:  `sapply(readLines("myfile", 6), charToRaw)`

Comment: Added the output to the post. Now even if am replacing all "tabs" with commas via Vim, I am faced with same error on R. http://i.imgur.com/ZCLdwM7.png

Comment: Try adding `skipNul=TRUE` to the `readLines` call. Also note that the ff fe at the beginning of the file means it is a byte reversed unicode file. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/using-byte-order-marks

Comment: Added new output with skipNul = TRUE argument. I do not understand if you mean that "byte reversed unicode" is the problem in that file? If it is, can it be fixed? My understanding of hex code output is nonexistent.

Comment: I was just mentioning the meaning but I don't think that is the problem.